# Xcode loads an old instance of an image instead of a newer one

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView which loads an image called logo.png. I used Interface Builder to create the UIImageView and to add the image. I added a newer version of the logo by removing the old reference and moving it to trash and then adding the new reference with the same filename.

The problem is this: in Interface Builder, the logo displays the new image, but when I build and run the app on my device, it displays the old logo.

I have done these things trying to troubleshoot the issue: deleted the app entirely from the device and re-built it from xcode; removed logo.png from the project and added it again.

Is this just an xcode glitch or are there any other steps I can take to ensure the newest version of the image displays when the app runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uninstall your app from simulator.
Clean and buils and run your appp from xcode.

Comment: Thank you. Cleaning succeeded and the build loaded the correct logo.

Comment: Done and done. Thanks for your quick response. I'm used to just browsing here; this was my first question.